# Multiple Schema.org events, and what is an "event"

Tags: google-search, schema.org, rich-snippets

I want to use a schema for a travel event, a guided tour, but I am a bit confused with Google Developers line:

> Don’t promote non-event products or services such as "Trip package: San Diego/LA, 7 nights" as events.

Do they mean don't promote events that don't have specific dates? My event has specific dates and would be a table of dates something like:

- > ACME Factory Guided Tour 1 | 3 days | ACME landmarks (with times/dates)
- > ACME Factory Guided Tour 2 | 2 days | ACME accidents (with times/dates)
- etc.

Also Google states: "Each event MUST have a unique URL (a leaf page) and markup on that URL", but I want to have several schemas on the page for the various tour dates.

So how would you have multiple events on a single page, like a table with all the travel dates, and is a tour with dates an event? Obviously there is no performer, and the venue is different every day. Would this be inappropriate?

Answer (score 2):

Events usually refers to a live on stage events such as concert, lecture, or festival.

```
 Tour packages cannot be considered as events.
```

If you want to markup multiple events in a single page consider HTML markup instead of json-ld.